# Is a comma accurate here? "high and low, time and again"

Tags: punctuation, commas

Sentence:
I have an RC helicopter. I maneuver it high and low [,] time and again.

So is it "high and low, time and again", or "high and low time and again"?

The sentence without the comma seems awkward. But I am not sure if I should put a comma between them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rephrasing is not a valid answer on this site, but the sentence has no alternative but to rephrase. Comma isn't a solution here.

> I maneuver it high and low [,] time and again.

The problem arises not because there are two adverbial phrases but because two unrelated adverbs are juxtaposed. Separate the adverbial phrases to improve readability.

> Time and again I maneuver it high and low.

Answer (score -2):

"High and low" and "time and again" are both adverbial phrases. "High and low" modifies the verb "maneuver," and "time and again" modifies "high and low." Adverbs that modify each other are normally not separated by a comma.

But you're right, the phrasing is awkward and could be confusing. It would be best to rephrase the sentence to avoid the issue.